# Talend Open-Studio Supported I/O Formats

Tags: database, file-format, etl, talend, data-integration

I'm considering Talend's Open Studio for a Data Integration / ETL project, and I can't seem to find a list of formats for which it can input from or output to *out of the box*. For instance, I'm comparing it against Pentaho's Kettle, which I found supports File System I/O, MS Excel, Access, XML, JSON, SAP, various SQL databases, etc., out of the box. Where can I find similar information for Talend?

By "out of the box" I mean without having to code some Java plugin to do the conversion manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to look into this is to check out the Talend components reference guide from their download page: http://www.talend.com/download/data-integration (click on the User Manuals tab).

The Reference Guide PDF describes **all** components that come with Talend out of the box and will include all possible formats you can use.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list of all the Talend connectors, including the connection methods: 
http://www.talendforge.org/components/

All of the formats that you mentioned are supported.